# Passing local CQL commands file to Cassandra Docker container

Tags: docker, cassandra, cql, cqlsh

Is it possible to pass a local file for CQL commands to a Cassandra Docker container?

Using `docker exec` fails as it cannot find the local file:

```
me@meanwhileinhell:~$ ls -al
-rw-r--r--  1 me me  1672 Sep 28 11:02 createTables.cql

me@meanwhileinhell:~$ docker exec -i cassandra_1 cqlsh -f createTables.cql
Can't open 'createTables.cql': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ‘createTables.cql'
```

I would really like not to have to open a bash session and run a script that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The container needs to be able to access the script first before you can execute it (i.e. the script file needs to be inside the container). If this is just a quick one-off run of the script, the easiest thing to do is probably to just use the [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) command to copy the script from your host to the container:

```
$ docker cp createTables.cql container_name:/path/in/container
```

You should then be able to use `docker exec` to run the script at whatever path you copied it to inside the container. If this is something that's a work in progress and you might be changing and re-running the script while you're working on it, you might be better off mounting a directory with your scripts from your host inside the container. For that you'll probably want the `-v` option of [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v-read-only).

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is only for setting up a Jenkins e2e environment, so this solution works perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want docker container sees files in host system, the only way is to map volume. You can mapped current directory to /tmp and run command again `docker exec -i cassandra_1 cqlsh -f /tmp/createTables.cql`